How do I verify that a SMB server requires signing, preferably with Powershell?
How do I verify that a SMB server requires signing, preferably with Powershell?  I'd like to try to connect to an SMB server from client unsigned without negotiation and see that it fails, but succeeds when signing is enabled.
I can create a connection with New-SmbMapping -RemotePath '\\THE.IP.ADD.RSS' and get current connections with Get-SMBConnection | fl * but that seems to always be signed and successful; I am looking for a command that attempts unsigned and fails if signing is required.

If you have wireshark installed, you can use the command line tshark to capture a connection to your server, and then inspect the traffic to get the "ground truth". I used a few code snippets from my previous project and blended them together with Claude, which is not able to be posted on SO, but I've shared it here: https://gist.github.com/Mike-Crowley/4aa9d0913ef0518e79034e5cdc56daf4

I haven't used Wireshark in a while, but starting it, it appears I have no interfaces other than "Event Tracing for Windows (ETW) reader"--even when running as Administrator.  Not sure why I cannot see my Ethernet interfaces.

It would be tough to troubleshoot that from here, but I'd check to ensure you've got Npcap installed (prompted during the wireshark install) and that the bindings on the NICs in question (ncpa.cpl) have the filter driver selected. Perhaps uninstall and reinstall if needed.

Yep, the Npcap install as part of wireshark got blocked by corporate policies.  Running the installer elevated fixed this issue.

Aha, yes, I thought you said it was running as administrator, but that's def the most common issue. Glad you got it rolling.

Wireshark was indeed running as administrator, but I recalled that the installation did not.

Using Wireshark, I captured calls to powershell command New-SmbMapping -RemotePath '\\HOSTADDRESS', viewing the packets with a Wireshark filter (_ws.col.info == "Negotiate Protocol Response"). In the content of each such response, under SMB2 > Negotiate Protocol Response, it will tell me the Security mode, both for "Signing enabled" and "Signing required".
Note that the similar flags on the request tell you nothing about what the server is requiring, so be sure to be looking at the response packets, per the Wireshark filter I noted above.

Glad to see my approach worked for you! One other idea is just to use Nessus, but this kind of PowerShell wrapper for wireshark was fun to build, and can be adapted for future work.
